# Debian 8 upgrade but doesn't know it's online

Tags: networking, debian, debian-jessie

I just went through the upgrade from wheezy to jessie. When I login (KDE) and use System Settings to manage updates it says no network connection is available and it cannot download the updates it says are available. In the panel, the network settings applet also shows the system to be offline.

Actually all the other software has network access and I am online. I am using a static IP address; this configuration was working fine with wheezy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and set "managed" to true.

Credit: https://lists.debian.org/debian-kde/2015/06/msg00037.html